# how to Know which Selected Item DropDownlist in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

I want to have drop down list in MVC 5 and I want to  know that user which item selected.
I am searching and I find follow solution but in View code in Http.DropDownList error with

```
new{id ="dropdownlist1"}
```

My code is :

In my controller I have :

```
public ViewResult ExistHW()
    {
        #region
        List<SelectListItem> HWType = new List<SelectListItem>();

        HWType.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Monitor ", Value = "Monitor" });

        HWType.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Case", Value = "Case" });

     .....

        #endregion
        ViewBag.HWType = HWType;


        return View(); }
```

and I my View I Have:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("HWType", "-- select ---",new{ id = "dropdownlist1"} )

            $('#dropdownlist1').change(function () {
            jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("SelectType")', { id: $(this).attr('value') }, function(data) { });
```

That In my controoler :

```
public ActionResult SelectType(String value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {case "Monitor":
                break;
        case "Case":
                break;

      ....
        }
       return View();
    }
```

Comment: try using $("#dropdownId option:selected").val(); to get the value and $("#dropdownId option:selected").text(); to get the selected text.I think you are looking for the second one which is .text().

Comment: my problem is that no when work javav scripts

Comment: I don't understand, what did you say..?

Answer (score 0):

When calling `getJSON`, you are passing in and `id` parameter to `SelectType`. However, based on the signature of the action method, the parameter should be named `value`

Change `getJSON` call to:

```
jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("SelectType")', 
               { value: $(this).attr('value') }, 
               function(data) { });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change part of your page depending on selected item in your DropDownList you can use following sample and update it according to your case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        submitform = function (flag) {
            var ProductCatID = $("#ProductCategoryId").val();
            var param = { ProdCatID: ProductCatID, Flag: flag };
            var ul = '@Url.Action("GetProdPropertyValues", "ManageProducts")';
            $.ajax({
                url: ul + "?ProdCatID=" + ProductCatID + "&&Flag=" + flag,
                type: 'GET',
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result != "") {
                        $("#partialView").empty();
                        $("#partialView").html(result);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("R:" + xhr.responseText + " S:" + status + " E:" + error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductCategoryId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductCategoryId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ProductCategoriesSelectList, "Select", new { onchange = "submitform('dropdown')" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductCategoryId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SpecialName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SpecialName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpecialName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InitialPrice)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InitialPrice)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InitialPrice)
        </div>


        <div id="partialView">
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Controller for partial view:

```
public ActionResult GetProdPropertyValues(string ProdCatID, string flag)
        {
            if (flag == "dropdown" && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProdCatID))
            {
                ProductCategory category = db.ProductCategories.Find(Byte.Parse(ProdCatID));
                if (category != null && category.ProductProperties != null)
                {
                   return PartialView("ProdPropValues", category.ProductProperties);
                }

            }
            return PartialView("ProdPropValues", null);
        }
```